# Spline rendered behind column chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a column chart with two columns per point and n number of splines. The splines are rendering behind the columns in IE8, but works fine in chrome, I need this to work in IE8.

[image: Chart Image]

```
series: [{ data: [minReturn], name: "Minimum Projected Return" }, { data: [maxReturn], name: "Maxmimum Projected Return" },
    {
        type: 'spline',
        name: 'Target - ' + targetName0 + " : " + targetReturn0 + "%",
        data: [targetReturn0],
        marker: {
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3],
            fillColor: 'white'
        }
    }]
```

I add the extra splines dynamically:

```
riskReturnoptions.series.push({ type: 'spline', name: 'Target - ' + $('#targetname' + i).val() + " : " + parseFloat($('#targetreturn' + i).val()) + "%", data: [parseFloat($('#targetreturn' + i).val())], marker: { lineWidth: 2, lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[3], fillColor: 'white'} });
```

Then for each series add the point:

```
var pointcounter = 3;
    riskReturnchart.xAxis[0].setCategories(categoryArray);
    riskReturnchart.series[0].addPoint(minReturn);
    riskReturnchart.series[1].addPoint(maxReturn);
    riskReturnchart.series[2].addPoint(targetReturn0);
    for (i = 1; i <= targetno; i++) {
        riskReturnchart.series[pointcounter].addPoint(parseFloat($('#targetreturn' + i).val());
        pointcounter++;
    }
    riskReturnchart.redraw();
```

Comment: It would be great if you create a fiddle of your code !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of series you can set zIndex, see [docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#series.zIndex).

Now just set for splines higher `zIndex` than for columns.